# Modal not visible in Twitter boootstrap

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to display a modal on image click with the image which is clicked, but its not working.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ut2Ab/4/)

I am inserting the content of modal after the user clicks the image using

```
  $("#imageModal").html(modalHtml);
  $('#imageModal').modal('show');
```

This code might now work as I am getting the error: showModal is not defined but the same code is working on my website.
Please help find the issue.

Comment: Your fiddle had a few problems.  First, if you're going to put `onclick` handlers, you need to change `onLoad` to one of the "no wrap" options.  Also, make sure your external resources start with "http://" otherwise they become relative to the fiddle, e.g., "http://fiddle.jshell.net/ut2Ab/4/show/light/netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/..." which doesn't exist.  Also, www.netdna.bootstrapcdn.com isn't a valid domain.  Get rid of the www.  I updated the fiddle in your question.  Just keep this in mind going forward :-)

Comment: and you have included the js containing the showModal function in the page from where you are trying to invoke showModal?

Comment: Just thought Id point out a syntax error, you have <img id="activeImage" scr="' + src +    ..... should be <img id="activeImage" src="' + src +

Comment: Also why not just use the built in data-toggle to open the modal.  Thats the standard way of doing it with Bootstrap

Comment: @dunnless,yes I have, If you see the fiddle, you will see that on image click the page fades but no modal appears, same is happening on my website.

Comment: @KyleK, The "src is fine in original code", still I just get black fadded screen without the modal, and how do I use data-toggle in my case where I wish to display the image being clicked in my modal.

Comment: Simply wrap the images, in an <a href="#imageModal" data-toggle="modal"><img src=''source here'></a>   then in your jquery/Jscript put $('a').click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
    var i = $(this).find('img').attr('src');
    $('activeImage').attr('src', i);
    });  That should insert the image into the img attribute and open the modal.....I have it working in JsFiddle, but still with your problem of the actual divs not showing, and screen just blacking....I will post if I solve

Comment: Got your answer below :)  Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

First at the very top of your html body....directly after the `<body>` tag, and before any content.

Put your modal...without any img, just an empty body...

```
<div id="imageModal"  class="modal hide fade in">
<div class="modal-header"><a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</a>
  <h3>Select the area</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body"></div>
 <div class="modal-footer">
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Men Topwear</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Men Bottowear</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Women Topwear</a>
  <a href="#" class="btn btn-success">Women Bottomwear</a><br>
  <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
 </div>
```

Then later in your document, wherever you want the images...just wrap them in a `<a>` tags, and apply the name of the modal box to the href, and apply the data-toggle attribute... `data-toggle="modal"`

```
 <a class='galleryImg' href="#imageModal" data-toggle="modal">
      <img src="http://media.santabanta.com/gallery/global%20celebrities(f)/shakira/shakira-28-m.jpg" />
     </a>
 <a class='galleryImg' href="#imageModal" data-toggle="modal">
      <img src="http://media.santabanta.com/gal/event/ramaiya-vastavaiya-sp" />
     </a>
```

Then in your Jquery...simply find all the links with the class `.galleryImg`, or however you want to identify them, and apply a click handler...that passes the image, to the modal.

```
$('a.galleryImg').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var img = $(this).html();
    $('.modal-body').html(img);
});
```

Heres the [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/holoverse/ut2Ab/9/)

**UPDATE**

After looking at the code you pasted....you cant do it like that, as you are outputting two click handlers, on created items.  You need to do it like this...

```
function testAPI(){
listOfPage = ["http://media.santabanta.com/gallery/global%20celebrities(f)/shakira/shakira-28-m.jpg", "http://media.santabanta.com/gal/event/ramaiya-vastavaiya-special-screening/ramaiya-vastavaiya-special-screening-32.jpg"]
for (var i=0;i<listOfPage.length;i++){
     $("#imgbox").append('<a class="galleryImg" href="#imageModal" data-toggle="modal"><img src="'+listOfPage[i]+ '"></a>');
    }
}
```

And then sepereately have this outside of the loop....

```
      $('body').on('click', 'a.galleryImg', function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         var img = $(this).html();
         $('.modal-body').html(img);
     });
```

Because since you are appending the items, they are dynamically created so you need to use `on` instead of `click`

But you also need to wrap it all in a  `$(document).ready(function()`...like so

```
 $(document).ready(function(){


    //Facebook login function run/loop  
    function testAPI(){
      listOfPage = ["http://media.santabanta.com/gallery/global%20celebrities(f)/shakira/shakira-28-m.jpg", "http://media.santabanta.com/gal/event/ramaiya-vastavaiya-special-screening/ramaiya-vastavaiya-special-screening-32.jpg"]
     for (var i=0;i<listOfPage.length;i++){
       $("#imgbox").append('<a class="galleryImg" href="#imageModal" data-toggle="modal"><img src="'+listOfPage[i]+ '"></a>');
      }
    }


  //Apply click handler to dynamic links...
  $('body').on('click', 'a.galleryImg', function (e) {
     e.preventDefault();
     var img = $(this).html();
     $('.modal-body').html(img);
 });

  });
```

Comment: Your problem was also related to loading the css before the js.  I switched the external dependancies around on JsFiddle, and instead of adding bootstrap-modal.  I just added the complete bootstrap library.  Then the Bootstrap CSS AFTER the JS.  Make sure if you copy this to your main site, that you have Jquery loading first, then bootstrap.js, then bootstrap.css

Comment: hey kylek, thanks for putting in so much effort but this thing is still now working, here is the original html: http://paste.ofcode.org/33AQEw9dZvc7M6Hxmytq92V and the js: http://paste.ofcode.org/RRaSMpp7572n9xQwjPWi4X

function testAPI is fired on pageLoad. I am still getting black faded screen and no modal.
really thanks

Comment: I removed the "hide" class from main image div and I am getting the modal now but it is coming without the bg, eg: http://pastemehere.com/e0gxxpre